# Magento 2.3.x Admin Panel keeps loading

Tags: magento2, nginx, centos, php-fpm, mariadb

I have installed Magento 2.3.5-p1 and also tried 2.3.4-p2 on Centos 7, with Nginx & PHP-FPM, maria DB with following commands.

```
1. /var/www/magento < owner by MAGENTO:NGINX user (I have created a pool for magento:nginx)
2. find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
3. find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
4. chmod u+x bin/magento
6. su magento

7.  bin/magento setup:install --base-url='https://www.example.com/' \
--base-url-secure='https://www.example.com/' \
--backend-frontname='' \
--db-host='localhost' --db-name='' --db-user='' \
--db-password='' --admin-firstname='example' \
--admin-lastname='Admin' --admin-email='' \
--admin-user='admin' --admin-password='' --language='en_US' \
--currency='USD' --timezone='UTC' --use-rewrites=1 --use-secure-admin=1 --use-secure=1
```

Once completed, my FRONTEND (home page) works absolutely fine, i just have 2 errors in the javascript console log:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (requirejs-config.js, line 0)
[Error] Refused to execute https://www.example.com/pub/static/version1594092941/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs-config.js as script because "X-Content-Type: nosniff" was given and its Content-Type is not a script MIME type.
```

But when I open admin panel, I can login into it. However, after logging in it keeps loading. I have tried several methods available online such as:

> ```
> 1. rm -rf pub/static/* (except .htaccess) refresh page
> 2.  
> php bin/magento cache:clean
> php bin/magento cache:flush
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
> 3.
> vi app/etc/di.xml <-- Change Symlink to Copy
> rm -rf pub/static/*
> refresh page
> 4. 
> rm -rf var/*
> bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
> bin/magento c:c
> 5. bin/magento cache:enable
> ```

I have tried to install it under both `php-fpm` and `nginx` group, also as `nginx:nginx`. Nothing works, admin panel just keeps loading.

What am I missing here?

[The errors i get on admin panel JS console logs](https://pastebin.com/raw/QzZV6pT5)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright after days of troubleshooting I finally found the stupid issue that was related to `open_basedir`. However, i still don't know why that (Home Page) worked fine even when `open_basedir` in PHP was in affect. But only admin panel wasn't working.

So I disabled open_basedir in `php.ini` and reinstalled Magento 2, and I no longer had this issue.

> $ vi /etc/php.ini
>
> ;open_basedir=/....
>
> $ systemctl restart php-fpm
>
> $ bin/magento setup:install --.....

Answer (score 0):

just run this commands it will solve your isssue

```
php bin/magento config:set web/secure/use_in_adminhtml 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be permission issues.

```
sudo chmod -R 0777 var/ pub/ generated/
```

Comment: giving 777 permission is a not a recommended solution. however, you can and should give r/w permission to that specific user/group only e.g. 770. however my problem was with the open_basedir.